# Substitution AND capitalize on ${var}

Tags: bash, variables, substitution, capitalize

I have this piece of code :

```
target='xfce/*'
file_name="All files from ${target/\/*}"`
```

Later on, I do

```
echo "Copying [$file_name] folder"
```

and it shows :

```
Copying [All files from xfce] folder
```

I wanted it to show

```
Copying [All files from XFCE] folder
```

instead (notice that `XFCE` is now capitalized)

I know how to capitalize with `${var^^}`, but how can do both substitution and capitalization?

I tried

```
file_name="All files from ${target/\/*^^}"
```

or

```
file_name="All files from ${target^^/\/*}"
```

but none works. Is there a way to achieve substitution AND capitalization in the same command ?

Comment: Use a second variable to store the intermediate state.

Comment: if `var` is to *always* be capitalized then you could issue `declare -u var` early in your script so that all follow-on assignments to `var` will automatically be capitalized

Comment: it's not clear (to me) from the EDIT if you want `${target}` to be expanded during the assignment or the `echo`

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

```
remplacement=foobar; echo ${var//Pattern/${remplacement^^}}
```

Answer (score 1):

While nested variable expansion is not possible in Bash, in this particular case you could use the following one-liner:

```
echo $(tr '[:lower:'] '[:upper:]' <<<${var//pattern/repl})
```